# How do I make stone bricks in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I did it according to [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone_Brick) from the wiki, but it does not work. I'm in survival mode. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Make sure you are using Stone and not Cobblestone.

Comment: Just blow up tnt underground and pick up the floating stone blocks. If this doesn't work for you just smelt cobblestone using a furnace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put 4 **stone** (not cobblestone) in a square in your crafting screen.

You make stone by smelting cobblestone in a furnace.

You can't make cracked, mossy or chiseled stone bricks in survival. They are only found by harvesting them from temples or strongholds.

Answer (score -1):

Get a crafting table place 4 stone block one on top of each other and a brick block WILL appear next to the crafting table. To do this online you MUST have the latest version of Minecraft.

hope i could help :)

Comment: Does this add anything that the existing answer doesn't already say?